# PHP textbox Validation through pregmatch

Tags: php, validation

I want to check that a user input in textbox doesnot contains any special character. how can i validate text box without using any javascript/Jquery

Comment: Please post your code so far so we can help.

Comment: php supports only server side validation   use Ajax to valiidate from server  and bring back to client side

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `$name` is the user input,

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 _]+/i', $name)) {
// preg_match will return true if it finds 
// a character *other than* a-z, 0-9, space and _
// *anywhere* inside the string
}
```

Comment: thanks gv-me... can you tell me how to validate a number and email using the same method